# How can I test the Apple Pay outside US?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, applepay

I am integrating one of `Apple Pay` in one of my application with `Braintree` as a provider.

I am trying to initialise braintree by this

```
 [self.provider createPaymentMethod:BTPaymentProviderTypeApplePay];
```

I am getting this error on `didFailWithError` method

```
- (void)paymentMethodCreator:(id)sender didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

}

Error Domain=BTPaymentProviderErrorDomain Code=2 "Failed to initialize a Apple Pay 
authorization view controller. Check device, OS version, cards in Passbook and configuration." 
UserInfo=0x17487fc40 
{NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to initialize a Apple Pay authorization view controller. 
Check device, OS version, cards in Passbook and configuration.
```

To resolve this I'm trying to add credit card in the `Passbook` but which ever card I entered I get an error stating **it is not supported**.

It seems `Apple Pay` and `Passbook` only accepts specific credit cards provided by **American Banks** only

But as I'm living in India and I don't have any way progress further. How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your region (in Settings→General→Language & Region) to one of the supported regions, like United States or UK. After that, you can add a valid US/UK card.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the steps to add a credit card to a passbook.

- [setup credit card](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201239)

But currently they are supporting only US banks

- [supporting banks](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6288)

To overcome, you can add and verify for a credit card from the list of banks they supported and continue. But you should have an account in US, or ask a friend who can help you out with his credit card details.